# Get rows having different values for a column based on the duplicate values of combination of other 3 columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I want to get only rows having a different values in a column(column name DEF) based on the duplicate rows having unique combination of other 3 columns.

Example: In the below example first two rows has same value for first 3 columns.But they have different value for column DEF. So both these rows to be listed in output.

But rows 2 and 4 has unique combination for first 3 columns but they have same values in DEF column.So not to be listed in output.

rows 5 and 6 are not to be listed since they are single row with different values.

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| dept     | role1 |role2   |DEF     |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| a        | abc   | er     | 0      |
| a        | abc   | er     | 1      |
| b        | qwer  | ty     | 0      |
| b        | qwer  | ty     | 0      |
| c        | der   | ui     | 1      |
| d        | nerr  | io     | 0      |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
output

+----------+------+------+------+
| dept     | role1|role2 |DEF   |
+----------+------+------+------+
| a        | abc  | er   |0     |
| a        | abc  | er   |1     |
+----------+------+------+------+
```

I tried using distinct with having but not able to check the values of column DEF to get desired result.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using standard SQL on most RDBMS, there are various ways.

#### Using a subquery:

```
SELECT d.dept, d.role1, d.role2, DEF
FROM data d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dept, role1, role2 
    FROM data
    GROUP BY dept, role1, role2
    HAVING COUNT(distinct DEF) > 1
) dup
    ON dup.dept = d.dept AND dup.role1 = d.role1 AND dup.role2 = d.role2
;
```

The subquery returns sets of `dept/role1/role2` with more than 1 distinct `DEF`.

#### Using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT d.dept, d.role1, d.role2, DEF
FROM @data d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM @data 
    WHERE dept = d.dept AND role1 = d.role1 AND role2 = d.role2 AND DEF <> d.DEF
);
```

The subquery return 0 to n rows. If at least one row exists, the row from the main table is returned.

#### Using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT d.dept, d.role1, d.role2, d.DEF
FROM @data d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT n=1 
    FROM @data 
    WHERE dept = d.dept AND role1 = d.role1 AND role2 = d.role2 AND DEF <> d.DEF
) ca
;
```

CROSS APPLY works with Oracle or SQL Server.

#### Output:

```
dept    role1   role2   DEF
a       abc     er      0
a       abc     er      1
```